# The links rotate but end up in a completely different area of the page?

Tags: html, css

I would like the link to rotate in place but they end up rotating and being in a different area of the page..

```css
/* CSS: */

.link:hover {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<!--HTML:-->

<div class="link">
  <h2><a href="loufestfood.html">Food</a></h2>
</div>
<div class="link">
  <h2><a href="loufestent.html">Entertainment</a></h2>
</div>
<div class="link">
  <h2><a href="LfEntSched.html">Entertainment Schedule</a></h2>
</div>
<div class="link">
  <h2><a href="pastLouFests.html">Past Lou Fests</a></h2>
</div>
<div class="link">
  <h2><a href="LouFestSurvey.html">Take the Lou Fest survey!</a></h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hover the `.link`. I modified the code to have `<h2>` to be `inline-block` and hover over `<h2>`

```css
/* CSS: */

.link>h2 {
  display: inline-block;
}

.link>h2:hover {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<!--HTML:-->

<div class="link">
  <h2><a href="loufestfood.html">Food</a></h2>
</div>
<div class="link">
  <h2><a href="loufestent.html">Entertainment</a></h2>
</div>
<div class="link">
  <h2><a href="LfEntSched.html">Entertainment Schedule</a></h2>
</div>
<div class="link">
  <h2><a href="pastLouFests.html">Past Lou Fests</a></h2>
</div>
<div class="link">
  <h2><a href="LouFestSurvey.html">Take the Lou Fest survey!</a></h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set [`transform-origin` CSS attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) value to control the transformation origin for your rotated tag:

```css
/* CSS: */

.link:hover {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!--HTML:-->

<div class="link">
  <h2><a href="loufestfood.html">Food</a></h2>
</div>
<div class="link">
  <h2><a href="loufestent.html">Entertainment</a></h2>
</div>
<div class="link">
  <h2><a href="LfEntSched.html">Entertainment Schedule</a></h2>
</div>
<div class="link">
  <h2><a href="pastLouFests.html">Past Lou Fests</a></h2>
</div>
<div class="link">
  <h2><a href="LouFestSurvey.html">Take the Lou Fest survey!</a></h2>
</div>
```